# What's a better workaround compiling both OpenMP and single-threaded versions of an algorithm?

Tags: c, multithreading, macos, include, openmp

I use an ugly workaround to compile the same source code once for OpenMP and once for single-threaded code. It includes compiler macros and a double #include of a C file. I'm looking for a better solution.

OpenMP and Mac threads don't mix. This is apparently well-known. Quoting from http://www.imagemagick.org/script/architecture.php#threads .

> The OpenMP committee has not defined the behavior of mixing OpenMP
>   with other threading models such as Posix threads. However, using
>   modern releases of Linux, OpenMP and Posix threads appear to
>   interoperate without complaint. If you want to use Posix threads ...
>   from Mac OS X or an older Linux release, you may need to disable
>   OpenMP support within ImageMagick.

I have a Python library with a C extension which scales very nicely with OpenMP, and it really involved only a scattering of #pragma statements and the right compiler flags.

I also develop on Macs. When I use my library in something other than the main thread, I get a segfault. For example, if I use OpenMP support then I can't use my library in Django.

I could of course compile without OpenMP support, but then the single-threaded batch code, which does well with OpenMP, wouldn't work.

I instead want a user-defined function to select at run-time between the OpenMP implementation and the single-threaded implementation.

The only solution I've come up with is a horrible hack where I #include the same C code twice:

```
#ifdef _OPENMP

#define MYFUNC static int _myfunc_openmp
#include "algorithm.c"
#undef MYFUNC
#define MYFUNC static int _myfunc_single
#include "algorithm.c"

int myfunc(int arg) {
  if (omp_get_num_threads() <= 1) {
      return _myfunc_single(arg);
  } else {
      return _myfunc_openmp(arg);
  }
}

#else

#define MYFUNC int myfunc
#include "algorithm.c"

#endif
```

and where "algorithm.c" looks like

```
MYFUNC(int arg) {
#ifdef _OPENMP
  #pragma omp for ...
#endif
   ... algorithm here ...
}
```

This does work, but it feels like I'm taking the wrong approach.

I tried using OpenMP's "if()" clause, as in

```
  int in_parallel = (omp_get_num_threads() > 1);
  #pragma omp for ... if(in_parallel)
```

but that still causes OpenMP on a thread to segfault my program. I presume that it's allocating space for the lock in the critical section of my code, even though it's not needed.

Do you know a better way to have the same algorithm used for both the OpenMP and non-OpenMP code paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have C99 (gcc and clang do for that case) you can use the `_Pragma` operator. It is useful especially inside macros:

```
#ifdef WITH_OPENMP
# define PARALLEL_FOR _Pragma("omp for")
#else
# define PARALLEL_FOR
#endif
```

Now you can just prefix the appropriate `for` loops with that macro, and thus avoid all other the ugly `#if/#else` in the rest of the code, which make it difficult to maintain.

The double inclusion per se of the file doesn't look wrong to me. Having a special case that is compiled statically without OpenMp avoids any run time decision that OpenMp could try to take.

What I wouldn't do, is passing storage specification, return type and name in one macro. In any case having the two functions visible by the linker costs you nothing, so the `static` is superfluous. The only thing that you should watch is that linker symbols starting with an underscore are reserved, better rename them to something decent.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out _Pragma! It looks like MSVC doesn't accept it, but instead uses __pragma. I'll experiment. I think I'll just use the double #include (which more shows C's lack of 'real' macros rather than is wrong). And I'll change my functions to remove the "_". That habit migrated over from Python's naming experience.